# Get file list from S3 using Api Gateway proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Im trying to get list of files from S3 bucket using ApiGateway. How should look my GET request from ApiGateWay ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use API Gateway as the proxy to S3, probably the best way how to start is to import an example API provided by AWS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-as-s3-proxy-export-swagger-with-extensions.html

the only thing you have to do is to replace the ARN of role in the json, i.e. replace all 
"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/apigAwsProxyRole" with your own role ARN (don't forget to provide the proper permissions to role through IAM console)

Once this is done just import the file through API Gateway console. It will create you a new API called MyS3 where the GET method you looking for looks like this.

[image: AWS API Gateway console]